# How to get this code to run?

Tags: java

I have tried to run this code (In 3 different classes - A, B, and C) and it's not running. I cant figure out why not. Can anyone help please?

```
public class A {    

    private int number;
    protected String name;
    public double price;

    public A ( ) {
        System.out.println ( "A( ) called"); }

    private void foo1( ) {
        System.out.println( "A version of foo1( ) called"); }

    protected int foo2( ){
        System.out.println( "A version of foo2( ) called");
        return number; }

    public String foo3( ){
        System.out.println( "A version of foo3() called"); 
        return "Hi";            
    }
}
```

---

```
public class B extends A {

    private char service;

    public B ( ) {
        super( );

        System.out.println( "B( ) called"); }

    public void foo1 ( ) {
        System.out.println( "B version of foo1( ) called"); }

    protected int foo2 ( ){
        int n = super.foo2( );
        System.out.println( "B version of foo2( ) called");
        return ( n+5 ); }

    public String foo3 ( ) {
        String temp = super.foo3 ( );
        System.out.println( "B version of foo3( )");
        return ( temp + " foo3" ); } }
```

---

```
public class C extends B {

    public C( ){
        super( );
        System.out.println( "C( ) called"); }

    public void foo1 ( ) {
        System.out.println( "C version of foo1( ) called" );
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it?  What is the exact Exception or Error you are seeing?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "it's not running"? Does it compile? What do you expect it to do and what does it actually do? Does the program start but do the wrong thing, or can you not start it at all?

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried.Com](http://WhatHaveYouTried.Com)?

Comment: Have you considered using public static void main(String[] args)?

Comment: Take a close look at the error message it will guide you to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have the `main` method to specify the start of the program. You need to create a main method in one of your classes with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that and every time I'd insert it (no matter what class) it gives me errors.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should allow your program to run

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    a.foo2();
    a.foo3();

    //same for B and C
}
```

Comment: This will never compile. Since method foo1() in Class A is private method.

Comment: @Jayamohan ah yes sorry for the oversight, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more class in the same package. For example, I have create one class named Application like below:

```
  public class Application{
         public static void main(String []args){
                A a = new A();
                a.foo3();
                B b = new B();
                b.foo1();
                C c = new C();
                c.foo1();
         }
  }
```

And then, please try to run it again...

Comment: This will never compile. Since method foo1() in Class A is private method.